# Paying taxes to a corrupted government

Tags: halacha, money, transactions, business, taxes

There are many countries with corrupted governments who steal taxpayers' money. **Is one still obliged to pay taxes if the government is corrupted and steals a big fraction of the taxes one pays?** What's the point of paying taxes if tax revenue gets stolen anyway?

Comment: Governments don't steal, don't oppress, don't discriminate, don't sin, etc - people do. So as long as the gvm governs and controls the order in the country, it is completely legit as DD"M.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hershel Schacter wrote a nice piece on this very topic. In short, he explains that in the times of the Talmud the king would collect a tax. If the tax would be unfair than dina dimalchusa would not apply. However, nowadays we don't look at taxes the same as the times of the Talmud. Rather we view each neighborhood as partners and the taxes go towards the "partnership" of the neighborhood.  These taxes pay for , police, fire, garbage, and so on. Most of taxes go to things that people need and want. However, if you would live in a place where a tax is taken in a very apparent unfair manner, then per the Shulchan Aruch it isn't Dina demalchulsa anymore.

Article link:

https://www.torahweb.org/torah/special/2005/rsch_taxes.html

Comment: All you do to address the question is to say that it "might be a question". This doesn't seem like an answer to me.

Comment: Is that how you read the answer ?! Its pashut that in a normal country where they provide services using tax money then one cannot say it's unfair. However, in a country where the taxes are unfair then one would not have to pay like the talmud and SA,the reason I ssy it may be a question is because I do not know what country he has in mind .

Comment: I don't know what country he has in mind either, but I'm pretty sure any place today where you can live openly as a Jew isn't corrupt enough for that Sh"A to apply.